# Scrapy returns repeated out of order results when using a for loop, but not when going link by link

Tags: python, scrapy

I am attempting to use Scrapy to crawl a site. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class ArticleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "article"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for linknum in range(1, 15):
            next_article = response.xpath('//*[@id="NewsImageVerticalItems"]/div[%d]/div[2]/h3/a/@href' % linknum).extract_first()
            next_article = response.urljoin(next_article)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_article)


            for text in response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_BodyLabel"]'):
                yield {
                    'article': text.xpath('./text()').extract()
                        }

            for tag in response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_bodytext"]'):
                yield {
                    'tag1': tag.xpath('./div[3]/p[1]/a/text()').extract(),
                    'tag2': tag.xpath('./div[3]/p[2]/a/text()').extract(),
                    'tag3': tag.xpath('./div[3]/p[3]/a/text()').extract(),
                    'tag4': tag.xpath('./div[3]/p[4]/a/text()').extract()
                        }
            yield response.follow('http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161', callback=self.parse)
```

But this returns in the JSON a weird mixture of repeated items, out of order and often skipping links: https://pastebin.com/LVkjHrRt

However, when I set linknum to a single number, the code works fine.

Why is iterating changing my results?

Comment: First tell us what *should* be the result, i.e. what you expect to obtain.

Comment: I want the text and tags of each article on the page, one time each in the JSON file.

Comment: Why are you yielding this request again and again at the end of loop `yield response.follow('http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161', callback=self.parse)` ?

Comment: That is what the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) does.

Comment: @TarunLalwani The purpose is to continue to repeatedly return to the stating page so that other articles can be accessed.

Comment: But that would not work because you are will be using a duplicated URL which will be filtered and not attempted in next round. And when you are at a UrL you can extract all information proceed to next stage, you should not need to visit the same URL again?

Comment: @TarunLalwani  I have attempted to fix this by putting the `yield response.follow('http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161', callback=self.parse)` at the first line of the first for loop and removing the callback, but it still does not work. Is it for the same reason as you explain? If so, I'm not understanding. Even removing the line entirely does not fix the issue.

Comment: I checked the url and your approach is not right. The Load more button may look the same url but it executing javascript and loading the page in background. You need to look at the network tab and you will see pages are generated with urls as `http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161/page2/` and you should be scraping these and not through so many xpaths as such. You should re-evaluate your strategies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TarunLalwani already stated, your current approach is not right. Basically you should:

1. In `parse` method, extract links to all articles on a page and yield requests for scraping them with a callback named e.g. `parse_article`.
2. Still in `parse` method, check that button for loading more articles is present and if so, yield a request for URL of a pattern [http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161/page*N*](http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161/pageN). (This can be found in browser's developer tools under XHR requests on network tab.)
3. Define `parse_article` method where you extract the article text and tags from details page and finally yield it as item.

Below is the final spider:

```
import scrapy

class IrnaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'irna'
    base_url = 'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.base_url, meta={'page_number': 1})

    def parse(self, response):
        for article_url in response.css('.DataListContainer h3 a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(article_url), callback=self.parse_article)

        page_number = response.meta['page_number'] + 1
        if response.css('#MoreButton'):
            yield scrapy.Request('{}/page{}'.format(self.base_url, page_number),
                                 callback=self.parse, meta={'page_number': page_number})

    def parse_article(self, response):
        yield {
            'text': ' '.join(response.xpath('//p[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_BodyLabel"]/text()').extract()),
            'tags': [tag.strip() for tag in response.xpath('//div[@class="Tags"]/p/a/text()').extract() if tag.strip()]
        }
```